# Replace an Dictionary object in Array using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have one dictionary object in Array.

I want to replace this object with new dictionary.

Both have same order_id.

Currently I am doing it like, How can I do it with NSPredicate.

```
NSMutableArray *orderList=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  objectForKey:@"Orders"];

        //2. Find and replace the object/OrdeDetails.
        for(int i=0;i<orderList.count;i++){

            NSDictionary *dictionary=orderList[i];

            if([dictionary[@"order_id"] isEqualToString:OrderDetails[@"order_id"]]){

                [orderList replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:OrderDetails];

                break;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use NSPredicate for this, if the above works?

Comment: You can not replace the object with `NSPredicate`, you can simply find that objects.

Comment: Yes I thought that for finding we can use NSPredicate. So we can skip few lines of for loop.But I think for loop is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code:

```
 NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                        predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.order_id contains[cd] %@",OrderDetails[@"order_id"]];
 NSMutableArray *arrOrders = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [arrOrders addObjectsFromArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Orders"]];

 NSArray *filteredOrder = [arrOrders filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

 if ([filteredOrder count] > 0) {
       NSUInteger index = [arrOrders indexOfObject:[filteredOrder objectAtIndex:0]];
       if (index != NSNotFound) {
           [arrOrders replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:OrderDetails];
       }
}
```

Comment: More appropriate than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace an object with `NSPredicate` you can however search for it then do the replacement afterwards.

Well just made this up without testing but I do think it has a valid syntax.

You can use this as the foundation or hope you get the logic in using the predicate.

```
// construct the predicate with the given condition
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"order_id = %@",dictionary[@"order_id"]];

// this will filter the array according to the given predicate. if there are more than 1 entries with the given condition then you should handle that this only handle unique entries
NSArray *array = [orderList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

// assuming that order_id is unique
NSInteger index = [orderList indexOfObject:[array lastObject]];
if (index != NSNotFound) // check if index is existing
  [orderList replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:orderDetails]; // replace the object with the desired object
```

Comment: Yes Joshua, that is the approach, but bit triky, otherwise for loop is good. Thanks @Joshua

Comment: not really tricky but just need to understand how predicate works. I think this is a good way to get to know NSPredicate [cheat sheet](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/)

Comment: All answer look same, my answer need to have some pointer understandings, but still I will use for loop. It is a less complex.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to match perfect then I used, LIKE. Although I am not sure.
Got from the link[cheat sheet](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/)

```
    NSPredicate *predicateSearchOrder=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.order_id LIKE[cd] %@",[responsedDict valueForKey:@"order_id"]];
            //
            //        //It will be only one object with order id.

NSArray *searchedArray=[orderList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateSearchOrder];

if(searchedArray.count>0){
            NSDictionary *toModiFyDictionary=searchedArray[0];
            toModiFyDictionary=OrderDetails;
}
```

This is also working

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Swift, It's very simple.

```
public class Test : NSObject {
    class func test() -> Void {
        var array : [Dictionary<String, String>] = []

        let dic: Dictionary<String, String> = ["order_id" : "111", "name" : "good1"]
        let dic2: Dictionary<String, String> = ["order_id" : "222", "name" : "good2"]

        let dic3: Dictionary<String, String> = ["order_id" : "111", "name" : "good3"]
        array.append(dic)
        array.append(dic2)

        let result = array.map { (elem) -> [String : String] in
            if elem["order_id"] == "111" {
                return dic3
            }
            return elem
        }
        print("result = \(result)") 
    }
}
```

Comment: In essence, it is also a for loop